# How to configure custom Google Assistant device with Google Home App?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I am developing a custom Google Home device using Google Assistant SDK. I have developed custom actions as well for my device. Now I am at a stage of doing the production of the device. The problem is that I have to manually download credentials.json and put it into the device. For production, I want to use Google Home App instead of manually copying credentials.json, so that end users can configure the device using Google Home App. I am trying to figure out the way to do this in Google Assistant SDK documentation but unable to find it. So is there a way to use Google Home app for configuration of custom Google Assitant Device? Or Google Home App does not support it yet?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Home app does not support setting up third-party devices with user credentials. Only after the device is authenticated as the user can it modify settings through the app.

Comment: Can you please provide me the reference to Google Assistant SDK documentation where this is mentioned? I need it.

Comment: Here are the docs for the device settings in the Assistant app: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/assistant-app/assistant-settings

Comment: It does not talk about you cannot configure the device with Google Home app.